# I keep receiving an indentation error and I shouldn't be

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, urllib2, xlsxwriter

I'm getting an Indentation Error whenever I run my program in CMD. To me, the indentation throughout the program looks perfect so I have absolutely no idea why I'm receiving the error.

CMD Error:

```
        scraper9.py", line 50
            browser.get(url2)
            ^
        IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

I have completely removed all indents and re-indented line for line to arrive the current iteration but I still errors out.

import os
                import sys
                import csv
                from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
                import urllib2
                import xlsxwriter
                from selenium import webdriver

```
            reload(sys)
            sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")

            key_stats_on_main = ["Market Cap", "PE Ratio (TTM)"]
            key_stats_on_stat = ["Enterprise Value", "Trailing P/E"]

            stocks_arr =[]
            pfolio_file = open("tickers.csv", "r")
            for line in pfolio_file:
                indv_stock_arr = line.strip().split(",")
                stocks_arr.append(indv_stock_arr)

            print(stocks_arr)

            browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
            stock_info_arr = []

            for stock in stocks_arr:
                stock_info = []
                ticker = stock[0]
                stock_info.append(ticker)

                url="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}?p={0}".format(ticker)
                url2="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}/key-statistics?p={0}".format(ticker)

                browser.get(url)
                innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
                soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, "html.parser")
                for stat in key_stats_on_main:
                    page_stat1 = soup.find(text = stat)
                    try:
                        page_row1 = page_stat1.find_parent("tr")
                        try:
                            page_statnum1 = page_row1.find_all("span")[1].contents[1]
                        except:
                            page_statnum1 = page_row1.find_all("td")[1].contents[0]
                        except:
                            print("Invalid parent for this element")
                            page_statnum1 = "N/A"
                        stock_info.append(page_statnum1)

                browser.get(url2)
                innerHTML2 = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML2")
                soup2 = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML2, "html.parser")
                for stat in key_stats_on_stat:
                    page_stat2 = soup2.find(text=stat)
                    try:
                        page_row2 = page_stat2.find_parent("tr")
                        try:
                            page_statnum2 = page_row2.find_all("span")[1].contents[0]
                        except:
                            page_statnum2 = page_row2.find_all("td")[1].content[0]
                    except:
                        print("Invalid pareent for this element")
                        page_statnum2 = "N/A"
                    stock_info.append(page_statnum2)

                stock_info_arr.append(stock_info)

            print(stock_info_arr)

            key_stats_on_main.extend(key_stats_on_stat)
            workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Stocks01.xlsx")
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
            row = 0
            col = 2

            for stat in key_stats_on_main:
                worksheet.write(row, col, stat)
                col +=1

            row = 1
            col = 0
            for our_stock in stock_info_arr:
                col = 0 
                for info_bit in our_stock:
                    worksheet.write(row, col, info_bit)
                    col += 1
                row += 1
            workbook.close()
            print("Script completed")
```

I expect the code to execute without Ineation errors.

It errors out. I'm so lost.

Comment: Are you mixing spaces and tabs? Try normalising whitespace using your editor/IDE's tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `try:` lacks an `except:` or `finally:`.

```
            for stat in key_stats_on_main:
                page_stat1 = soup.find(text = stat)
                try:  # <--------------- this one here
                    page_row1 = page_stat1.find_parent("tr")
                    try:
                        page_statnum1 = page_row1.find_all("span")[1].contents[1]
                    except:
                        page_statnum1 = page_row1.find_all("td")[1].contents[0]
                    except:
                        print("Invalid parent for this element")
                        page_statnum1 = "N/A"
                    stock_info.append(page_statnum1)
                      # <---------------- needs something here
            browser.get(url2)
```

You probably meant the second `except:` to be on the indenting level of the first `try:`:

```
            for stat in key_stats_on_main:
                page_stat1 = soup.find(text = stat)
                try:  # <--------------- this one here
                    page_row1 = page_stat1.find_parent("tr")
                    try:
                        page_statnum1 = page_row1.find_all("span")[1].contents[1]
                    except:
                        page_statnum1 = page_row1.find_all("td")[1].contents[0]
                except:
                    print("Invalid parent for this element")
                    page_statnum1 = "N/A"
                stock_info.append(page_statnum1)

            browser.get(url2)
```

Try that!

Btw, you should reduce the size of the code in your `try:` clause and catch only the exceptions you are handling.  In your case, an `AttributeError` (if `.contents` fails) would be caught by the first `except:`.  Better:

```
try:
    found = page_row1.find_all("span")
    index = 1
except XError:  # should be the one .find_all() can raise
    found = page_row1.find_all("td")
    index = 0
page_statnum1 = found[1].contents[index]
```

And something similar for the outer `try`/`except`.

This way you do not cloak other exceptions you never meant to handle.  If you do that cloaking, you will have a hard time figuring out what's going wrong, so avoid it.

Comment: Wow, damn. Mini lesson in coding right there. Thank you Soo much!